# Re-Generating Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Is there any way to re-generate views from newly updated model?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you've made a lot of changes to the scaffold, it's probably easier just to overwrite the current scaffold:

```
./script/generate -f scaffold Model
```

Comment: What is -f ?
      Couldn't find '-f' generator

Comment: -f, or --force, will overwrite files that already exists. You can run script/generate scaffold to see all available options.

Comment: Should be `rails g scaffold Model -f` or `rails generate scaffold Model --force`.
Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @totocaster 'Couldn't find '-f' generator' error is when you didn't put -f or --force option at the right place! Put it after model name.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need, I just backed up some changes and did a destroy/generate, **Take care, destroy deletes Everything related to the Model**  :

`rails destroy scaffold Model -f`

before I generate again.

`rails generate scaffold Model`

Answer (score 1):

The scaffold is not intended to *create* the interface, only to make a starting point for further development. I'm not sure it's even possible (without a lot of unnecessary work) to redo a scaffold, it's much quicker to manually edit the view and controller anyway.